# Can I change the hardware button mapping with CM9 (Samsung Galaxy S2)?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-2, samsung-touchwiz

I have a GS II and recently flashed to CM9  - I wanted to know if there's any way to map the hardware buttons back to the TouchWiz shortcuts - specifically the long press menu button = search (I really used that and seriously miss it).

On that note - I also wanted to know if there are any TouchWiz ports of only the shortcuts (right swipe call / left swipe message etc.) for CM9 or any other slim/clean ICS ROM.

Answer (score 2):

With ButtonRemapper you can remap certain keys, but long press is currently not supported. It might be implemented in the future though, I suggest you follow the topic: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=850464

Comment: What is the `ACTION` for task manager?

Answer (score 2):

The keymap file for Cyanogen is in `/system/usr/keylayout/qwerty.kl`.

All you have to do is find a way to change this file (never forget backup). Of course that requires your device to be rooted, you could easily do that using [Root Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedsoftware.rootexplorer). Android loads keymap configurations on boot, so any changes while the system is running need a restart.

I'm not sure how long press is mapped on this file, My search function does work long pressing the menu. I checked it out, and found these two lines:

```
key 127 SEARCH WAKE_DROPPED
key 217 SEARCH WAKE_DROPPED
```

Check out if these lines matches yours in your file, and if not, change it to a similar way.